# Extracting ObjectId from a JSON string

Tags: java, json, mongodb

How to extract Object Id of a JSON string before inserting it into MongoDB? 
Also how to set Object id as primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the MongoDB generates `ObjectID("507f191e810c1972xxxxx")` by its own (if you do not set it). As mentioned in the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started/#create-a-collection-and-insert-documents):

> All MongoDB documents must have an _id field with a unique value. These operations do not explicitly specify a value for the _id field, so mongo creates a unique ObjectId value for the field before inserting it into the collection.

In this article [ObjectID](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification) described BSON ObjectID specification. The format includes:

> 1. TimeStamp. This is a unix style timestamp. It is a signed int representing the number of seconds before or after January 1st 1970
>      (UTC).
> 2. Machine. This is the first three bytes of the (md5) hash of the machine host name, or of the mac/network address, or the virtual
>      machine id.
> 3. Pid. This is 2 bytes of the process id (or thread id) of the process generating the object id.
> 4. Increment. This is an ever incrementing value, or a random number if a counter can't be used in the language/runtime.
>
> The server itself and almost all drivers use the format above.

After successful insertion the `_id` which holds `ObjectID("507f191e810c1972xxxxx")` is returned by most of the drivers.

---

**Primary Key & Index**:
`_id` field is reserved for primary key in MongoDB and that should be an unique value. If you don't set anything to `_id` it will automatically generates `ObjectID("507f191e810c1972xxxxx")` as mentioned above.

MongoDB creates the default `_id` index, which is a unique index on the `_id` field. MongoDB creates this index by default on all collections. You cannot delete the index on `_id`. For more information here is the [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-single/#cases)

Answer (score -2):

there are many json libraries you can use for that, for example, google's gson:
https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
after you add the JAR file you can use the method fromJson method to get the object.
http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html

Comment: please provide a proper answer.Is there any method to find the id of  json string

Comment: if your type has an ID as a property, you use the fromJSON method and you get your object, then use the dot notation to get its id